# ASP NET Chart columns overlapping multiple labels

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a chart on which I display some numbers as the `Y values` at the dates that this numbers originate on the `X axis`.

The problem I have is that not only the dates I am using are displayed but also other dates within the interval. Also the real problem is the columns for my dates are spread over multiple labels.

How can I avoid this ?
In the aspx file:

`<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 33px" Width="700px">`

```
                            <ChartAreas>
                                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
                                </asp:ChartArea>
                            </ChartAreas>
                        </asp:Chart>
```

In code-behind:

`protected void Page_InitComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
        }`

`void button_click ( )`
`{`

```
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBind( chartData, "ResultDate", "ResultCount", "");
```

`}`

Where chartData is an `Array` with a ResultDate and  A ResultCount :

`8/2/2013 12:00:00 AM , 2`
`8/21/2013 12:00:00 AM ,3`

The result is that multiple dates are displayed inside this interval and the columns overlap more than their date.

Comment: Seems hard to answer without some example code from my perspective.

Comment: @Brian Just updated the question.

Comment: What chart library is this? Telerik?

Comment: @Brian This ASP.NET Charts

Comment: Perhaps there is an option in Chart1.Series["Series1"] that you can adjust to change your interval range. The problem seems to be that the Series object generates the range between the 2 dates and the series object is generating a more detailed range than you desire.